# How to calculate order of infinitesimal?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, estimation, approximation-theory, infinitesimals

The first part of the exercise requires stating the order of:
$$h(x)=\lim_{x\to0} (1+4x)^{1/4} + \ln(1-\sin(x)) - 1$$

I approximated $(1+4x)^{1/4}$ as $1/4\times4x$, that is $x$, and $\ln(1-\sin(x))$ can be approximated as $x$.

(That is, $-\sin(x)\sim -x$, and $\ln(1-x)\sim -x$ for $x$ sufficiently small.)

I'm conflicted because according to the solution my teacher put online, it should be an infinitesimal of the second order. I noticed she used little-o notation but I couldn't make heads or tails as to why there was an $x^2$ and $o(x^2)$ in there.

The other part of the exercise requires calculating $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{h(x)}$ and I can see that equaling a constant only if $h(x)$ is an infinitesimal of the second order ($1-\cos(x)\sim \frac{1}{2}x^2)$.

Comment: $\ln(1-\sin x)\sim -x$ !

Comment: yes I combined the logarithm and the sine one to approximate it like that

Comment: So what are you missing ?

Comment: It's just that it's not correct if I do it that way.

Comment: Still having a hard time figuring out why it doesn't and why I have to use Taylor Expansions.

Comment: Please show your complete computation, otherwise we cannot help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$(1+4x)^{1/4}=1+x-\frac32x^2+o(x^2)$$

$$\ln(1-\sin(x))=\ln(1-x+o(x^2))=-x-\frac12x^2+o(x^2)$$

therefore

$$(1+4x)^{1/4}+\ln(1-\sin(x))-1=-2x^2+o(x^2)$$

and then for the second part

$$\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{h(x)} =\frac{\frac92x^2+o(x^2)}{-2x^2+o(x^2)}=\frac{\frac92+o(1)}{-2+o(1)}\to -\frac94$$

Comment: where can I find the first two transformations (what are they called)?

Comment: @besnn They are [Taylor's expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Comment: This is the exact solution the teacher gave.

Comment: @besnn Let me know if something is not clear to you.

Comment: If we did cubic polynomial approximations of the first two addends, would it still be of the second order (since the cubic term doesn't cancel out)?